# XSD validation on front-end and highlighting the invalid entries against the line for the respective XML

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, xml

I have an application that converts `XML->JSON-LD` and vice versa. Users can provide either `XML` or `JSON-LD` and the tool would convert the input into the respective format. I have 2 separate `HTML textarea` where one would handle `XML` and another `JSON-LD`.

I have predefined `XSD` and `JSON-Schema`. I am looking for a front-end library that can be integrated with my `HTML Textarea` to validate the `XSD Schema` and `JSON-Schema` and highlight the wrong entries/missing entries against the respective line.

Basically, I want to compare the provided XML with XSD and JSON with JSON Schema and highlight the wrong entries so the user will know if there are any mismatches. I want to highlight the wrong things against those lines. I know there are libraries that can provide all wrong entries which can be displayed to users but my requirement I want to display against the respective line. Any help or example would be really beneficial.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, there is no XSD processor that will do validation client-side in the browser.

I have had one sitting on the shelf 90% complete for several years (it's written in XSLT) but I've never got round to finishing it.